# Displaying multi values from a MS Access table to a form textbox field

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

I've just come across an issue. My MS Access table has multi tick boxes from its drop down as it lookup a table called **TRSTeams** with each team(s) can been associated with an application (Application one-to-many **TRSTeams**).

However the values are not being displayed in the text field called **txtTRST** on my form (Application) and just shows a blank field.

Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub lstName_Click()
      
     Set rstAM = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table11", dbOpenDynaset)
        
     Do Until rstAM.EOF
            
         If Me.lstName = rstAM![Name] Then
       
             Debug.Print Me.lstName
                       
             Me.txtName = rstAM![Name]
             Me.txtRrer = rstAM![Prerequisite]
             Me.txtType = rstAM![Type]
             Me.txtResp = rstAM![Responsible]
             Me.txtDeta = rstAM![Details]
             Me.txtTRST = rstAM![TRSTeams]
             Me.txtStar = rstAM![FromStart]
             Me.txtMeth = rstAM![Method]
             Me.txtNote = rstAM![Notes]
             
             ''Debug.Print Me.txtResp
                        
             Exit Sub
             
             Else
                     
             rstAM.MoveNext
            
         End If
    
    Loop

End Sub
```

[MS Access lookup tab for **TRSTeams**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0q5N.png)

Above is the current setup for **TRSTeams**

Comment: Your picture shows the query needed to retrieve the values. Your case demonstrates why most abandon MV fields. It's a dead end causing only but troubles.

Comment: ok, thanks for your input. what would the alternative for my issue?

Comment: Create a query that joins Table11 and tblTeams, save it, and use this query to open `rstAM`.

Comment: Why are you using VBA to load textboxes as opposed to opening a bound form filtered to record? Need to understand what MV fields are. MV field utilizes a hidden table to store multiple records. The field really just stores pointers to these hidden records. Managing MV field with code gets complicated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245029/how-do-i-use-access-vba-to-update-a-multivalue-field