# How to edit values in Lookup-field via VBA (Recordset)

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently making a Shift-Scheduler in MS-Access.
Im using a Table with a Multi-Selection Lookup-Field to pick the workers supposed to work that day.

Now Im trying to create some supportive buttons to faster insert the workers.
For Example putting a worker in on a shift every day of a week (Something thats quite usual to happen).

For that case I need to somehow edit the Multi-Selection Lookup-Field and add the worker to the Selection or overwrite the whole Selection with a new one.

Sadly, I can't insert a String via Recordset thats set up like the values are saved in the table (eg. "1; 3; 6").

Is there someone who could support me here?
Thanks in advance!

```
enter code here

Private Sub btn_apply_Click()

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim Apotheke As String
Dim Schicht As String
Dim startdatum As Date
Dim enddatuma As Date
Dim strMitarbeiter As String

If Nz(Me.txt_von, "") = "" Or Nz(Me.txt_bis, "") = "" Or Nz(Me.comb_apotheke, "") = "" Or Nz(Me.comb_schicht, "") = "" Or Nz(Me.list_ma.Selected(1), "") = "" Then
    MsgBox "Bitte fülle zuerst alle erforderlichen Felder aus!"
    Exit Sub
End If

result = MsgBox("Dadurch wird der Schichtplan geändert! Dieser Vorgang kann nicht Rückgängig gemacht werden! Fortfahren?", vbYesNo, "Warnung!")
If result = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Apotheke = Me.comb_apotheke
Schicht = Me.comb_schicht
startdatum = Me.txt_createfrom
enddatum = Me.txt_createtill

For Each ma In Me.list_ma.ItemsSelected
    If strMitarbeiter = "" Then
        strMitarbeiter = ma
    Else
        strMitarbeiter = strMitarbeiter & ", " & ma
    End If
Next

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from TBL_Schichten where [Standort] ='" & 
Apotheke & "' and [Schicht] ='" & Schicht & "' and [Abgerechnet] = FALSE order by 
[Datum] ASC")

Do Until rs![Datum] = startdatum
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Do Until rs![Datum] > enddatum
    rs.Edit
    rs![Mitarbeiter] = strMitarbeiter
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

MsgBox "Done!"
```

End Sub

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use Access VBA to update a multivalue field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245029/how-do-i-use-access-vba-to-update-a-multivalue-field)

Comment: Must understand that multi-value field is really just holding links to records of a hidden dependent table. Alternative is to build normal related tables and form/subform for data entry. I NEVER use multi-value field.

Comment: I heared that Multivaluefields aren't used pretty often.

What exactly do u mean with your Alternative?
How Do I include something similar into a subform?

Comment: I don't really understand your confusion. Do you not understand how to set up related tables and form/subform for data entry?

Comment: This is how my Table looks right now:
https://i.postimg.cc/B6017m5n/Inked-Form.jpg

Its 1 Table with a Subtable all within 2 Subforms.
In the List with the names on the right one can choose 1 or more Workers to work that day.
And thats basically the whole Problem. The field is a Multi-Value field.
Is there a way to have a similar Multi-Selection field, without the use of Look-upfields in the Basetable?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have never used datasheet/subdatasheet mode. I use form/subform. In your case, maybe form/subform/subsubform. A multi-value input without a multi-value field would usually involve in UNBOUND multi-select listbox and VBA code to save each selected item to a separate record.

Comment: Addendum: I use form/subform in Single or Continuous mode. I provided you a link to example of saving data to multi-value field. Did you look at? More info https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-lookup-and-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a

Comment: Thanks for your Advise. I did what you mentioned and used an extra Form with an unbound Multivalue field. Isn't as good looking in the Form, but works way better for the backend.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unbound Multivalue field". Did you mean UNBOUND multi-select listbox?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I'm not a native English speaker and my MSAccess isn't in English too. So translating things like that is though.