# In Microsoft Access VBA using DAO, how do you set a multivalued field when adding a record?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, dao

I have a two tables:

`Discrepancy`, and `Code`

Discrepancy is a general database that has various information. One of its fields, type, is multi-valued and comes from the Code database.

Code has ID, Code, and Description.

Originally, I tried setting the field by using a string separated by semicolons:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Discrepancy", dbOpenDynaset)
rs.AddNew
'rs![...] = ...
rs![Type] = "1;2;3"
'rs![...] = ...
rs.Update
rs.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

That didn't work, so I tried to create a function and set the type to that:

```
Private Function get_codes(ByRef rs As DAO.Recordset) As DAO.Recordset2
  rs.MoveFirst
  Set get_codes = rs![CodeChart_Code].Value
End Function
```

This function appears to work in order to get the codes, but when trying to set it, I get the error "Method 'Collect' of 'recordset2' failed. I have tried using this as a DAO.Recordset and a DAO.Recordset2, with the same issue.

Comment: May be this helps: [How do I use Access VBA to update a multivalue field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245029/how-do-i-use-access-vba-to-update-a-multivalue-field)

Comment: I saw that and misunderstood its use. I have revisited it and yes, that is what I needed. Thank you!