Combine multiple values into a multivalue field
I'm trying to get an sql query to convert rows with the key in one table into a multivalue field.
Here is my sql query:
SELECT L4Process.ID, L3Process2.ID, Requirements.ID AS Expr1, Requirements.Title AS Expr2
FROM Requirements INNER JOIN (L4Process INNER JOIN L3Process2 ON L4Process.ID = 
L3Process2.L4ProcessStep.Value) ON Requirements.ID = L3Process2.Requirements.Value
ORDER BY L4Process.ID, L3Process2.ID, Requirements.ID;

which gives me a result set of this:
L4Process.ID    L3Process2.ID   Expr1   Expr2
2   1   5   Ability to transfer consignment inventory from one consignment location to another
2   1   6   Consignment Report (Analytics) - Report on Short term loan inventory held in consignment
2   1   7   Waiting for billing in consignment - Hold off on completing Consignment Issue (Goods Issue) until Customer PO number is received
2   1   8   Consignment Report (Analytics) - consignment stock by region by customer location
2   1   10  Ability to enter and track batch numbers on consignment orders
2   1   12  Ability to report stock held on consignment by a sales person (trunk stock)
2   1   14  Ability Sell stock held on consignment to the end customer and determine correct local company address VAT #
3   1   5   Ability to transfer consignment inventory from one consignment location to another
3   1   6   Consignment Report (Analytics) - Report on Short term loan inventory held in consignment
3   1   7   Waiting for billing in consignment - Hold off on completing Consignment Issue (Goods Issue) until Customer PO number is received
3   1   8   Consignment Report (Analytics) - consignment stock by region by customer location
3   1   10  Ability to enter and track batch numbers on consignment orders
3   1   12  Ability to report stock held on consignment by a sales person (trunk stock)
3   1   14  Ability Sell stock held on consignment to the end customer and determine correct local company address VAT #
4   1   5   Ability to transfer consignment inventory from one consignment location to another
4   1   6   Consignment Report (Analytics) - Report on Short term loan inventory held in consignment
4   1   7   Waiting for billing in consignment - Hold off on completing Consignment Issue (Goods Issue) until Customer PO number is received
4   1   8   Consignment Report (Analytics) - consignment stock by region by customer location
4   1   10  Ability to enter and track batch numbers on consignment orders
4   1   12  Ability to report stock held on consignment by a sales person (trunk stock)
4   1   14  Ability Sell stock held on consignment to the end customer and determine correct local company address VAT #
5   2   4   Ability to include additional item categories (such as Free of Charge or Standard Line Items (TAN)) on a Consignment Issue Order
5   2   9   Ability to model returns of loan stock within demand planning
5   2   11  Ability to carry physical inventory of stock held on consignment at a customer site
5   2   12  Ability to report stock held on consignment by a sales person (trunk stock)
5   2   13  Ability to report stock held on consignment at a customer site
5   2   15  Ability to move stock between customer consignment locations
5   2   16  Ability to sell stock held on consignment directly to the customer

I want to enter the values for Expr1 as a multivalue field corresponding to L4Process.ID.  This column will be the available choices. It needs to go into "Field1" of the second table
ID  L4Process   Field1
2   S01.02.01.01-Customer Governance  (W)   
3   S01.02.01.01-Customer Governance  (W)   
4   S01.02.01.02-Search Customer (W)    
5   S01.02.01.04-Display Customer List (F)  
6   S01.02.01.04-Display Customer List (F)  
7   S01.02.01.05-Maintain Business Partner (F)  


I could be wrong but I don't think you can use SQL for this. I have done it with VBA on several occasions but those were very specific requirements. I would personally avoid the use of multivalue fields and opt for a separate table with the appropriate key fields instead. However if you really must go down this path then VBA will likely be your only option. See this link for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245029/how-do-i-use-access-vba-to-update-a-multivalue-field?rq=2

SQL can APPEND data to multi-value field https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-lookup-and-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a#bm7. However, I don't know if a batch APPEND is possible, never tried. I also advise not to use MVF.

I just confirmed can do INSERT INTO tablename (MVFname.Value) SELECT ID FROM othertable.

Trying to understand table relationships. Which is the "one" table and which is the "second" table? What purpose will this MVF serve? If a query can produce the dataset, why do you need to save into MVF?
